# Get all guest & customer email id's in single collection Magento 2

Tags: admin, collection, grid, magento-2.2.5

I am trying to list all unique email id's (guest & customers) in admin grid to restrict specific email id to place order.

For that, I got an id's from customer collection and order collection.

But I need this in the single collection.

```
name | email
A    | aa@aa.com
B    | bb@bb.com
C    | cc@cc.com
```

FYI:

```
/* \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory */
$customerCollection = $model->getCollection();
$customerCollection->getSelect()
    ->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
    ->columns(
    [
        'name' => "CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname)",
        'email' => 'email'
    ]
);

/* \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory */
$orderModel = $this->_orderFactory->create();
$orderCollection = $orderModel->getCollection();
$orderCollection->addAttributeToFilter('customer_is_guest', ['eq' => 1]);
$orderCollection->getSelect()
    ->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
    ->columns(
        [
          'name' => "CONCAT(customer_firstname, ' ', customer_lastname)",
          'email' => 'customer_email'
        ]
    );
```

Even I tried with preparing a new collection `\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection` && `\Magento\Framework\DataObject` in this cases filter, page size, cur page not working.

After collecting those data need to list in admin grid.

Please suggest the possible way?

Thanks

Comment: you want a merge collection base of customer entity and another is ordered table?

Comment: why you want this , Can you please explain your purpose?

Comment: @AmitBera yes, i want just name, email for all guest and customer. some cases I need to restrict order placement for a specific customer and some fake mail ids. Note: here using offline payment

Comment: @AmitBera any updates

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have any idea on two different type of collection join.

*So far my understanding, you can follow below also as an alternative solution.*

***Make two collections and filter those collections using email of current quote or order email***

Comment: I have an idea, main problem union not working as expected in the collection. `Make two collections and filter those collections using email of current quote or order email` - i guess you didn't get my point.

Comment: Why you need a large collection  without  page size and limit , and it make page  slow

Comment: Are you talk abount `CONCAT(customer_firstname, ' ', customer_lastname)`?

Comment: no, finally go with different solutions (creating a new model to store emails which needs to block from order placement). thanks amit